# why does my CSS + HTML web pages display differently in IE & FireFox?

Tags: html, css

My code has been validated by w3school yet it still displays differently in IE and firefox.

My link bar allong the top seems to cascade down in IE but displays in a stright line (as it should be ) in Firefox!!!

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lbf.css">

<title>Love British Film</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<div id="main_container">fegerfg

    <div id="header">
    <div class="logo">Love British Film.com </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul class="nav_list">

        <li class="odd"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="index.html">Reviews</a></li>
        <li class="odd"><a href="index.html">Forums</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="index.html">Videos</a></li>
        <li class="odd"><a href="index.html" >Downloads</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="index.html">News</a></li>
        <li class="odd"><a href="index.html" >Fun bits</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="index.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>




        <div class="main_text">
        <div class="header">HEADER FOR MAIN CONTENT</div>


        Main content!!
        </div>

        <div id="film_of_day">Film of day </div>




        <div id="poll_of_week">asdnasdljasasdasfdasfasfas</div>




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And My CSS code

```
body
{
background:url(bg.jpg) no-repeat #FFF center top;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
margin:0px auto auto auto;

}

div {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 0px;
}

#main_container{
width:1200px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
padding:0px;
}
#header{
position:relative;
width:1200px;
height:170px;
background:url(header.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-position:0px 0px;
margin:auto;
padding:5px;
}
.logo{
width:auto;
height:auto;
font-size:20px;
position:relative;
top:80%;  
text-align:right;
}
.nav_bar{
width:1200px;
height:50px;


}
ul.nav_list{
list-style-type:none; float:left; display:block; width:1200px; 
margin:0px; padding:0px;
}

ul.nav_list li.odd a{
display:block;width:150px; text-align:center; float:left;text-decoration:none; background:url(images/home.png) no-repeat left; 
background-color:rgb(147,216,255);height:40px; line-height:40px; color:rgb(168,100,63);
}
ul.nav_list li.even a{
display:block;width:150px; text-align:center; float:left;text-decoration:none; background:url(images/home.png) no-repeat left; color:rgb(168,100,63);
height:40px; line-height:40px;background-color:rgb(26,142,165);
}
a.odd:link, a.odd:visited {
display:block;width:133px; text-align:center; float:left;text-decoration:none; background:url(images/home.png) no-repeat left; }
ul.nav_list li.even a:hover{background-color:#A29;}
ul.nav_list li.odd a:hover{background-color:#F99;}

a.even:link, a.even:visited {
display:block;width:133px; text-align:center; float:left;height:40px;text-decoration:none; background:url(images/home.png) no-repeat left; color:#676d77;}
a.even:hover{
color:#FFFFFF;
}



.header{
width:500px;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:50px;
}
.main_text{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
width:600px;
height:600px;
background-color:rgb(147,216,255);
}

#film_of_day{
float:right;
width:340px;
height:250px;
background-color:rgb(147,216,255);

}


#poll_of_week{
margin-top:50px;
float:right;
width:280px;
height:250px;
outline:solid;
padding:1px; 
}
```

Comment: Just for reference I'd be concerned if you code had been validated by 'w3school'...

Comment: @dougajmcdonald god, please post it as an answer so I can upvote it :-D EPIC !

Comment: Why should I be concerned? I uploaded my HTML and CSS files ton the W3 validator check website and it returned all green and good????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are floating your `a` tag inside your `li` tag which isn't good practice and causing your problems.

You should float your `li` tag and leave your `a` tag un-floated inside as the link

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmhzA/1/

Comment: Thank you trapper!!! that sorted my cross browser problems!!! now I just need to check my code with other browsers... Thanks again :)

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the real world.
IE and Firefoy interpret CSS different from each other. This was always a problem, and it will always be ! If you want to reduce different behaviours or looks, you could try to use a so called CSS reset.

**What is a css reset ?**
This is a simple css file, which resets every positioning, padding,margin, everything that comes by default from the browser to zero. So you can ensure that most of your styling will be interpreted the same. Sure still it will not alway be the same, but it helps you to put it in the right direction. You could also use GridLayouts for positioning, which is also a great tool and works and looks the same in the most browsers.

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
- http://960.gs/

And just a hint, open it with opera,chrome, elder verions of IE, safari and you will be astonished that it also looks different ;-)